# Strategy for Order

Tags: scrolls

I picked Order for my starter deck, liking the idea of having troops that feed off eachother in a strong formation. Unfortunately I get destroyed Mercilessly by other decks. Out of 20 games I have accomplished 2 wins on easy. I have been playing trading card games all my life, its almost unimaginable to me to lose so horribly.

I've learned that I need to hold my cards and stack up resources, then putting out troops at once so they are on the board in a strong formation. I'll use sacrifice attack if they play early weak monsters. Even if I do manage to get a strong formation going they usually just play spells that kill my weaker troops that buff my stronger troops, very slowly dwindling down my force. I just never have enough troops to handle the artillery from energy and the massive force of wolves from growth.

The couple times I was able to win, was against growth and I was able to keep the brothers from amassing lots of wolfs. I really need to know what is the trick behind Order, what should I be my opening strategy that leads me into a strong end game, so i'm not stuck with no troops and spell after spell card.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm no expert at Scrolls, but I also started with the Order deck and here are some of my strategies. I've mostly focused on Growth decks, but they a lot of them are applicable against other deck types.

- To counter growth decks, I've found the best strategy is to try to focus on buffing your relentless soldiers ([Ducal Skirmisher](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Ducal_Skirmisher) and [Royal Skirmisher](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Royal_Skirmisher)) with enchantments. This will allow you to cut through multiple weak monsters off of one cool down, helping to avoid the swarm of weak monsters.
- Try to block low HP monsters with Spikey creatures ([Ducal Spearmen](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Ducal_Spearman) and [Royal Spearmen](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Royal_Spearman)). The spearmen are excellent at blocking the wolves growth decks love to throw out. If the wolf attacks a spikey 2 spearmen, then it dies from the two damage.
- Don't be afraid to let your idols get hit early on and focus on building up your front line. You want to try to keep the relentless soldiers alive while you get the correct enchantments. Use a combination of structures and spearmen to protect them and your idols.
- Don't forget you can sidestep attacks or move your creatures to get an attack off. I'm really bad about letting a creature get a free attack on one of my weaker creatures like the [Crossbowmen](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Crossbowman). On that same note, feel free to shift over a creature to take out the weaker creatures before they start overwhelming the field.
- I usually attempt to put spearmen in front of the [Royal Vanguard](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Royal_Vanguard) or [Honorable General](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Honorable_General). Then I will place the skirmishers on either side. In the back line I try to place crossbowmen or infantrymen.
- Try to [Powerbound](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Powerbound) your front line that are prone to die. Another great combo with [Powerbound](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Powerbound) is to attach it to a [Zealot](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Sinmarked_Zealot) before sacrificing him for an easy +1 Order.
- Don't be afraid to stack [Plate Armor](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Plate_Armor) on one creature that can completely ignore the weaker Growth creatures. Plate Armor also works with [Vengeance Veil](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Vengeance_Veil) even if the damage is reduced to 0 (I **think**, I believe I was successfully using this combo last night)
- Try to use your [Crossbowmen](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Crossbowman) to snipe stronger creatures. I hate to waste their high attack damage on the smaller creatures Growth likes to summon.
- Try to use [Blessing of Haste](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Blessing_of_Haste) on the [Honorable General](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Honorable_General) or [Royal Vanguard](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Royal_Vanguard). This combos with their special abilities to give massive buffs quickly. The [Vengeance Veil](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Vengeance_Veil) + [Plate Armor](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Plate_Armor) can also work on these creatures.
- I usually try to [Kabonk](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Kabonk) the [bunnies](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Bunny) before they spread, but don't be afraid to [Kabonk](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Kabonk) purely for the draw power. Also, try to use [Summons](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Summons) as soon as possible. This will help thin out your deck so you get to your better cards sooner. Plus the structure is helpful versus the Growth zerg rush.

### Problem Growth Cards:

I generally make a point to remove these from the field as soon as possible.

- [Ancestral Totem](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Ancestral_Totem)
- [Bunny](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Bunny)
- [Druid Burial Ground](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Druid_Burial_Ground)
- [Vitality Well](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Vitality_Well)
- [Brother of the Wolf](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Brother_of_the_Wolf)

Most of these cards have strong global buffs or help Growth swarm the field overwhelming the slower build up of Order cards.

Comment: Hopefully this is helpful, it is a bit of a spitball approach on tricks/tips that have helped me.

Comment: I like it, i typically just make powerbound a resource right off the bat instead of actually using it. I think some of my problem is just having to many spell/enchantment cards and not enough creatures.

Comment: One other recommendation... don't be afraid to sacrifice.  Early, throw away the cards that are the most useless for resources.  Later in the game, throw off your cheap units to draw 2 additional cards.  I've only played 9 games (but I've won 8.)  When I finally decided to "let go" of the cards I simply liked, or wanted to try, I was able to quickly get the cards I needed and then pull off the buff/debuffs I needed to win.